# How do i send email through Codeigniter on some event?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using Codeigniter. In a User management Module i want to send an email to user if status is activated. My Email code is working but there is problem with my condition check whether his status is changed or not. I mean i want to send email only if his status is changed to Active.

Below Is My Controller Code:

```
if($_POST['status'] == 'active') 
                        {
                                    $config = Array(
                                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                                    'smtp_host' => 'Myhost',
                                    'smtp_port' => 25,
                                    'smtp_user' => 'user',
                                    'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
                                    );


                                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


                                $this->email->from('test@test.com', 'Rajan');
                                $this->email->to($_POST['email']);
                                $this->email->subject('Your Account Has Been SuccessFully Activated.');
                                $this->email->message('Hi, We have created your Account. Please Login ');
                                $this->email->send();

                                if ($this->email->send()) 
                                {
                                    echo"Success";

                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                   echo '<p class="error_msg">That Email And Password Combination Does Not Exist !</p>';
                                }


                        }
```

When i edit a user and change his status it gets saved in database but the email is not fired. Please help me to solve this bug.

Comment: Read https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: @Manwal As i said my email code is working, it sends email in nomal conditions but i want to send email only when status is changed

Comment: Try this one 
if($_POST['status']==='active')
 {
   //My Email Code
  }

Comment: @Suvashsarker Did not work :(

Comment: if($_POST['status']=='active') { //My Email Code } , does this work?

Comment: No it did not see my updated question code @Suvashsarker

Comment: Actually There is not error but this code just doesn't get executed. The data is saved in database but the email is not fired

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89158/discussion-between-suvash-sarker-and-rajan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this `if($_POST['status'] == 'Active')` since  your status post value is "Active" (according to our discussion).  The double equal sign `(==)` is case sensitive when used to compare strings in PHP.